# Set password for user on CentOs with SSH

Tags: c#, ssh, centos

I'm trying to set a password for an user I add over SSH with my program.

This is my code so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SshStream ssh = new SshStream("IP", "root", "Password");
    ssh.Prompt = "#";
    ssh.RemoveTerminalEmulationCharacters = true;
    ssh.Write("adduser " + textBox1.Text);
    textBox3.Text = ssh.ReadResponse();
    ssh.Close();
}
```

How would I send these commands on button click:

passwd textbox1.text

then the server returns this:

```
New UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
```

and I need to fill in each line with the value of textbox2.text

I am using this library: http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
ssh.Write("thepassword\nthepassword | passwd " + textBox1.Text);
```

which basically pipes the two passwords to the passwd function